# Android Studio Resources Folder

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I picked up someone else's project and when I asked AS to add some folders to me in app, it turned out that they created another *resources* folder when I have my *res* folder. Should I move all my stuff to the *resources* folder created by AS to simplify its job?

Thanks

Comment: What exactly are the parent directories of these folders, and what type of stuff do they each contain?

Comment: Right now, the directory is 
C:\Users\Me\StudioProjects\ProjectXYZ\app\src\main
Then both folders are there. The resources one is empty and was generated by AS and the res contains all my xml files.

Comment: Interesting... I would suggest keeping the `res` folder and moving everything there.

Answer (score 1):

keep the folder called `res` and move everything there. `resources` is not a name that android studio or android sdk will recognize in the project structure.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest keeping the `res` folder and moving everything to that directory. This is because the `res` folder is something that will be recognised by Android and is also what is suggested on the official [Android Developer's website page here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#ResourceTypes) about resources.

Comment: Great! That's what I thought but seeing my IDE doing this put some doubt.